# How to plot the graph using all the dates in x axis?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis-labels

I want to plot a graph with all the dates in x axis.
Here is the code I used

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)


data <- readxl::read_excel("Sentinel-1 Metadata info.xls")
centroid <- slice(data,1)

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`Date of acquisition`, `Bperp(m)`)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = centroid$`Date of acquisition`, y = centroid$`Bperp(m)`, 
                   xend = `Date of acquisition`, yend = `Bperp(m)`)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[I got the graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jll7.png)

But I want to display all the dates in the format DDMMYYYY.

Comment: Is it the scaling of the x-axis you wish to change? Have a look at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html

Comment: Yeah,there are 12 dates to be displayed.I have seen it, but how do I add the scripts to mine?

Comment: The answers to the Question suggested by reviewer doesn't solve my issue.